# File.Exists() throws an error in my Visual Studio 2022 / ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use `File.Exists(Path)`, but I keep getting this "Compiler Error CS0119". I was looking into if I needed a special using statement.

I can't figure out why it is not working. I originally was trying to learn how to use it. The docs and all the answers when trying to check to see if a file existed basically lead to this answer, but when I try using it I get this weird error. If it is that I simply need to restart my computer because of this issue I will let you know.

I am using it correctly but I don't know what the actual issue is. Additionally, I actually used a string like `File.Exista("thisString")` to see if that would make a difference but it did not.

**UPDATE**

Even with the using statements `using System; using System.IO`, I still had to use `System.IO.File.Exists(Path)` I did not know that and I hope this helps many people out. I say that because this is an issue with the IDE or something for now allowing me to use just the using statement. Thank you @Elliveny

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you replace with System.IO.File.Exists(... ?

Comment: Yes it does but I have the ```using system.io;``` statement as well

Comment: ```using System;
using System.IO;``` I have both of these statements I am baffled that work like that

Comment: As you can see it says `ControllerBase.File` which is refers to `ControllerBase` class's [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0), not to `System.IO.File.Exists` method

Comment: You see in the error message that there is a method `ControllerBase.File` which by the scope resolution rules has precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)
```

since `ControllerBase` does also contain a definition of `File`.
And since you have both using statements, it is unclear which `File.` you want to use.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that. I was wondering why it gave me that funny error and the conclusion made no sense :)